# Пожалуйста, помогите добавить аудио шум, используя "mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB"

Tags: аудио, видео, ffmpeg, автоматизация, фильтры

У меня есть аудио с именем noise.mp3. И я хочу, чтобы `mpdecimate` не просто удалил все статические кадры, а заменил их черным экраном и/или аудио шумом (который я могу использовать в Adobe Premiere для редактирования) и соответвенно отдал мне изначальную длину видео.

Честно говоря, на самом деле я не хочу использовать именно этот способ... Я бы хотел использовать симбиоз плагина Duplicate Frame Remover (или эту функцию из mpdecimate) + Silence Remover для Adobe Premiere. Но проблема в том, что первый вариант просто удаляет их и выводит укороченное видео без пауз, а второй работает только на основе аудио (но у меня нет аудио в моем видео).

Следовательно, нужно чтобы вырезанные моменты выключились, перенеслись на другую дорожку или вместо статичных кадров добавить звуковой шум. Чтобы иметь возможность анализировать и редактировать их в дальнейшем. Как это работает в Silence Remover или AutoCut (но они работают только путем анализа звука):

[image: Пример как необходимо чтобы это выглядело (и как работает Silence Remover и т.п.)]

Я не смог найти такого симбиоза, поэтому хочу попробовать поместить звуковой шум вместо статичных кадров. И тогда я смогу использовать Silent Remover, чтобы автоматически нарезать всё это.

Я уже потратил много часов, пытаясь сделать это с помощью ChatGPT, но он не сработал. У меня осталось два пути: FFmpeg не сможет этого сделать /или/ разработчики помогут, как это сделать правильно!

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста!